# Excel displays dates as times only by default

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime

I use Excel a lot while analyzing data and most of that data comes from SQL Server Management Studio. So I'll execute a query and copy the result set using `Copy With Headers` and then paste it into Excel. Annoyingly, because SQL Server Management Studio always inserts a time of midnight, Excel insists on displaying the time only.

So the value is `2015-04-17`, but SSMS copies it as `2015-04-17 00:00:00.000` and Excel displays it as `00:00.0`. In most cases, our date fields don't contain times (or then the implicit midnight time) and I am not even a little bit interested in those. I want to see the dates.

I am aware that I can select the cells and then set their date format (selecting *Short Date* from the Ribbon does the trick) but this is something I have to do *every single time*. Does anyone know of a way to ensure the time is not copied by SSMS, or that the default display format in Excel includes the date?

Comment: Would it be possible casting the dates to `SMALLDATETIME` (without parts of seconds) or `DATE` (without time) before/while exporting?

Comment: At last you can try to convert your dates to a `varchar` type ;).

Answer (score 0):

It depends from cells formatting. You can change this formatting cells before pasting rows. For example, you can select the entire document, right click on cells, Click on "cells format"  (I have excel in another language, I hope I translated right) and format all cells as text.

In your specific case you can do this just on the columns you need.

Comment: I believe having all dates as text in Excel is not really the goal.

Comment: @AxelRichter, you are right. When you format cells you can format them to the required date/time format to display.